# Why is my rgb to uint32 preprocessor macro giving me a wrong colorcode?

Tags: c, bit-manipulation, bit-shift, bitwise-or

I am learning about bit wise operators and ran into this problem:

> In computer graphics, colors are often stores as three numbers,
> representing red, green and blue intensities. Suppose that each number requires eight bits, and we'd like to store all three values in a single long integer.
>
> Write a macro named `MK_COLOR` with three parameters (the red, green and blue intensities). `MK_COLOR` should return a `long` in which
> the last three bytes contain the red, green and blue intensities, with the red value as the last byte and the green value as the next-to-last byte.

The solution is:

```c
#define MK_COLOR(r,g,b) ((long) (b) << 16 | (g) << 8 | (r))
```

I don't fully understand how the solution works, so I will try to break down my understanding, lets say `r = 20` (10100), `g = 30` (11110) and `b = 40` (101000).

1. `b` is shifted left by 16 bits so we get `00010100 00000000 00000000`
2. `g` is shifted by 8 bits so we get `11110000`
3. there is a `|` OR operator which looks like this:

```
  00010100 00000000 00000000 
| 11110000 00000000 00000000
 ---------------------------
  11110100 00000000 00000000
```

4. the last step does OR on this result we got but with `r` which looks like this:

```
  11110100 00000000 00000000 
| 10100000 00000000 00000000
 ---------------------------
  11110100 00000000 00000000 // result
```

The result is `11110100 00000000 00000000` which is `15990784` in decimal. This result however is incorrect according to when I run the program and get `2629140` as the answer.

Why is it wrong? Could you please explain what I did wrong and how I can better my understanding of this?

Comment: Welcome. Please choose a title which is useful for others with the same issue. Thank you.

Comment: any suggestions?

Comment: You said "g is shifted by 8 bits so we get 11110000" but that is only shifted by 3. And later you used "11110000 00000000 00000000" which is shifted by 16.

Comment: i apologies if my calculations are incorrect, that is just my understanding hence why i would like some help bettering my understanding

Comment: *"g is shifted by 8 bits so we get 11110000"* No, we get 00011110 00000000

Comment: The macro should contain an assert statement that all of r,g,b are < 256. The macro does not perform any validity checks. You can call it with any integers.
`#define MK_COLOR(r,g,b) (assert(r<256 && g< 256 && b < 256), ((long) (b) << 16 | (g) << 8 | (r)))`

Comment: `int x = MK_COLOR(1,2,3);` -> OK, `x = MK_COLOR(100,1000,200)` -> `macro_test: macro_test.c:7: main: Assertion ``100<256 && 1000< 256 && 200 < 256' failed.`
Of course, the r,g,b's in the assertion should be braced. I forgot this. Sorry.

Comment: @avans In that case, also assert that they are not negative

Comment: `#define IN_RANGE(x,a,b) assert((x) >= (a) && (x) < (b))` Note: I chose half open interval

Comment: Ah, that makes a whole lot of sense!

Comment: @avans Well, at some point, instead of correcting (like e.g. using unsigned types) and adding features to that macro, one should write a proper function and test it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have mistake in your shift results. Let's break it up:

```
r = 20 = 0b00010100
g = 30 = 0b00011110
b = 40 = 0b00101000
(long)(b) << 16 = 0b 00101000 00000000 00000000
(long)(g) << 8  = 0b 00000000 00011110 00000000
(long)(r)       = 0b 00000000 00000000 00010100
    -------------------------------------------
Ored Result     = 0b 00101000 00011110 00010100 = 2629140
```

Comment: why do you OR them altogether? from my understanding aren't ```b``` and ```g``` OR'd first then the result is OR'd with ```r```?

Comment: It is the same, the end result is that if in any operand there is one in some position, there would be one in the result...

Answer (score 1):

You're unintentionally doing some extra shifts.

You start with:

- r = 00010100
- g = 00011110
- b = 00101000

Then:

- `b << 16` = `00101000 00000000 00000000`
- `g << 8` =  `00011110 00000000`  (you had initially shifted left by only 3)

Then you OR them all together:

```
  00101000 00000000 00000000
  00000000 00011110 00000000
| 00000000 00000000 00010100
----------------------------
  00101000 00011110 00010100
```

The mistake you made was you added zeros on the left, essentially performing an additional shift an changing the values.

Comment: why do you OR them altogether? from my understanding aren't b and g OR'd first then the result is OR'd with r?

Comment: @programme3219873 The shifted values of `b` and `g` are ORed first.  I did them together just to simplify the illustration.